# Integration test - how to test a method with no inputs and a render

Tags: grails, integration-testing

How does one integration-test (Grails) a controller with no inputs and a render view?    Here is my controller code and test;  the test looks correct but throws a "java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching grails test target pattern filter" error.  many thanks for your help.  -ryan

Controller code section:

```
class ReportSiteErrorsController {

    static allowedMethods = [reportError: 'GET', saveReportError: 'POST']

    def mailService

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def reportError() {
        render(view:'reportError', model:[]) 
    }
}
```

Integration Test:

```
@TestFor(ReportSiteErrorsController)
class ReportSiteErrorsControllerTests extends DbunitGroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    void "test report error"() {
        controller.reportError()
        assert view == "reportError"
    }
}
```

Comment: What command did you execute in your attempt to run the test?

Comment: grails test-app integration: nameoftest.groovy

Comment: yeah I'm not sure.  I've checked all my formats and input statements too.

Comment: I expect you have something goofy in the project.  If you can reproduce it in a simple app that you can push to github or somewhere similar, I will be happy to take a look.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I've checked all my formats".

Comment: If your DbunitGroovyTestCase extends GroovyTestCase, that is probably the problem.  You are using the JUnit 4 Test annotation in a JUnit 3 test.  Is that the case?

Comment: Actually, that is probably not the issue.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the extension off in your command line.  You are supposed to be specifying the name of the test, not the name of the file in which it is defined.

Use something like...

```
grails test-app integration: NameOfTest
```

Not something like...

```
grails test-app integration: NameOfTest.groovy
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for that.  I tried that just now - ran it twice - and still failed unfortunately.  "No tests found matching grails test target pattern filter"

Comment: That does not make sense to me.  If you checkout the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/integrationtestexample and run `grails test-app integration: Person` I expect that to work and if you run `grails test-app integration: Person.groovy` I expect it not to work.

Comment: I figured it out!  too many hours staring at the same screen - I had an import spock.lang.Specification line in there, so my tests had an identity crisis: I was trying to run Junit tests as Spock ones. :)

Comment: That does not make any sense either.  Something else must have changed.  Just having `import spock.lang.Specification` in the test is of no consequence.  It will not affect the compiled test at all if you aren't using Spock.  It is there only to tell the compiler where to find the `Specificaiton` class at compile time if you make a reference to it.  If you don't make a reference to it, the import will not cause any problems.  If you have a passing test and add the import statement back, the test will still pass.

Answer (score 0):

in Grails 2.4 the default syntax to test `render "hello"` would be:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage     instructions
 */
@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void "test something"() {
    controller.index()
    expect:
     response.text == "hello"       
}
}
```

The `assert` won't do for me. See also: [the Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.2/guide/single.html#testing)